# python nested if statements not working

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to make a game using pygame, and I've set up a couple of functions that I've tested and they work fine. However, in the code below, when I add a print statement to show if my code works, it prints on the first one but not the second.  Any help?

```
for square in row:
    tile_x = row.index(square)
    # print statement works here
    if self.x_pos - tile_x >= -4 and self.x_pos - tile_x <= 4:
        tile_x = 4 - (self.x_pos - tile_x)
        tile_y = 4 - (self.y_pos - tile_y)
        if square == 'G':
            display('Grass',tile_x,tile_y)
            # print statement doesn't work here
        elif square == 'T':
            display('Tree',tile_x,tile_y)
        elif square == 'B':
            display('Bush',tile_x,tile_y)
        elif square == 'R':
            display('Rock',tile_x,tile_y)
        elif square == 'S':
            display('Stone',tile_x,tile_y)
        # display function has been tested, and it works fine
```

Comment: It would help to see where/how you added this print statement.

Comment: I just used print('Grass here')

Comment: Then, the if statement is incorrect. `print(square)`, see what you get outside of the if

Comment: I am not sure how you created the entire program when you do not even know how the `if` statement work. Coming to the issue, It will go into the inner print when `square == 'G'` is `True`. If it is not going there, means `square` is not equal to `G`

Comment: You are nesting and that means that first instance that returns `True` will exit the loop and `display()` what you wanted. `print` will work on 1st `if` only if your square equals G.

Comment: If it would be of more help, I  could add more of my code

Comment: While you are already printing, print something useful, e.g. `self.x_pos, tile_x, square`

Answer (score 0):

I have just thought of something

I am using `row.index(square)`, which is finding the **first** 'g' square and using the tile_x of **that** first square. This means it thinks the square I'm looking for is not in the correct range to show on the map, so the first if statement returns False and it doesn't show up or print out.